# Papers related to prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, self-learning

I am going through the following work by Ramanujan- [Irregular Numbers](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram04.pdf). The results are given with no formal proof. However, I am trying to rigorously prove them. Also, I am  looking forward to read some papers which are similar to the one above. Can you suggest any good papers with similar content as the above paper ?